# Compare maximum values of labeled data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

supposed my dataset

```
  Name  Num Label
0   K    10    0
1   K    21    0 
2   K    31    0
3   K    41    1
4   Y    9     0
5   Y    19    0
6   Y    14    1
7   B    33    0
8   B    43    0    
9   B    77    1
10  B    89    1
```

Each name has numeric data, and the label is 0/1.

I want to compare the maximum value of label 0 with the maximum value of 1 and extract only those with the largest value of 1.

If I apply the logic I've said, those are K and B
(K - max label 0 : 31 < max label 1 : 41 , B - max label 0 : 43 < max label 1 : 89)

result what I want

```
  Name  Num Label
0   K    10    0
1   K    21    0 
2   K    31    0
3   K    41    1
4   B    33    0
5   B    43    0    
6   B    77    1
7   B    89    1
```

thank you for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get maximal values of filtered rows with aggregate `max`, then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for original `DataFrame` and compare by maximum values per groups with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
s = df[df['Label'].eq(1)].groupby('Name')['Num'].max()
df = df[df['Name'].map(s).eq(df.groupby('Name')['Num'].transform('max'))]
print (df)
0     K   10      0
1     K   21      0
2     K   31      0
3     K   41      1
7     B   33      0
8     B   43      0
9     B   77      1
10    B   89      1
```